# Two different version of ansible gives two different outputs for same ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, yaml

```
  - hosts: Ebonding
    become: yes
    become_method: sudo
    tasks
      - name: Clearing cache of Server4
        file: path=/weblogic/bea/user_projects/domains/tmp state=absent
        become: yes
        become_user: wls10
```

Ansible version 2.0.0.0 run the above playbook successfully::

```
    PLAY     ***************************************************************************

    TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
    ok: [ggnqinfa2]

    TASK [Clearing cache of Server4] *********************************************** 
    ok: [ggnqinfa2]

    PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
    ggnqinfa2                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

But latest version of ansible 2.5.0rc2 encountered below error::

```
PLAY [Ebonding] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [ggnqinfa2]

TASK [Clearing cache of Server4] ************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [ggnqinfa2]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Failed to set permissions on the temporary files Ansible needs to create when becoming an unprivileged user (rc: 2, err: chown: /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1520704924.34-191458796685785/: Not owner\nchown: /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1520704924.34-191458796685785/file.py: Not owner\n}). For information on working around this, see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html#becoming-an-unprivileged-user"}
 PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
 ggnqinfa2                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

How can i run this playbook by latest version of ansible successfully?

Comment: I think, it looks like a bug, and you should report it to developers.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are the user you're using (`wls10`) does not have write access to the remote temporary directory `/var/tmp`.

This can be overridden using `ansible.cfg` and set via `remote_tmp` to a directory you have write-access to -- or, a "normal temp directory" (like /tmp) that has the sticky bit set.

For more info, see
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_configuration.html#remote-tmp